# Xamarin.form wallpapers on Android and Ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I developed an application with Xamarin.Form it works very well on Android and also on Ios simulators but to my surprise when I deploy the application on Ios equipment the rendering is no longer the same.

Below are the captures

IOS
[Ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXS8q.png)

Android

[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqx6Y.png)

Please help

As xamarin.form does the same rendering I expected the same design on Ios but the rendering is good on Ios simulators but not on Iphone X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok

Here is the solution for displaying it
In the info.plist file you have to add this:

```
<key>UILaunchScreen</key>
  <dict/>
```

To make the page take up the whole screen

Regarding the black background, it is necessary to take into account the two modes of Ligth and Black theme of Iphone in its application.

Answer (score 0):

I give you some suggestions:

1. You could try to restart vc, clear the project, delete the bin folders and the obj folders and rebuild it. And iOS simulator you choose should also be iPhoneX.
2. In Settings App of iPhoneX, you could choose Display & Brightness section. Try switching Appearance from Light to Dark or Dark to Light to see if it make changes.

Hope it works for you.